# Show all book names in a category with a foreign key relation

Tags: python, django

When I click in a category I want to show all the books in that category automatically.

Let's say I am at `example.com/category/2`, I want somehow when the category.id is 2 to get the the Category.name, and then search(filter) at other model book.category and get the book.title

i would also appreciate if i could get some template code for the loop required to present the data.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural ="Categories" 
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)`
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='book_category', null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def category(request, category_id=1):
    category=Category.objects.get(id=category_id)

    return render(request, 'view_category.html', {
        'category': category,
    } )
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_id>\d+)/$', 'seminar.views.category'),
```

Answer (score 2):

In your template you can display all books from category like this:

```
{% for book in category.book_category.all %}
    {{ book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```